# How to set default value with an accessor value in Object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript, es5-shim

I want to be able to set new name upon instanciation of a new object. But somehow I got an infinite loop to be happening. I dont know how to fix it.

```
function Human(opt) {
  this.name = opt.name; //this causes ranger error or infinite loop
}

Object.defineProperties(Human.prototype, {
  name : {
    set : function(val) {
      if(name === 'Einstein') {
        console.log('Hello Einstein');
      }
      this.name = val;
    },
    configurable : false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no infinite loop in your code, but there would be if you changed this:

```
this.end = val;
```

to this:

```
this.name = val;
```

*(Question now updated to use `this.name = val;`)*

Because it would of course call the `set` again, and again...

What you need is something like your `.end` property to store the actual value, and then use a `get` accessor to retrieve the value from `.end`.

```
  get: function() { return this.end },
```

Comment: Sorry a typo. It should be this.name

Comment: I want `this.name` to be set when I use the `new Human({name: 'Einstein'})`

Comment: @Woho87: I know, but that's what causes the loop. If you want to use the `set` functionality, what you need is that when `.name` is set, your setter actually sets it to a different property. Then you set up a `get` for `.name` so that when you ask for the value of `.name` it'll get it from that other property.